# google map palace flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-places-api

I'm trying to fetch nearby places in my app, but there is some error.

If there is same topic please notice me

I'm looking forward for your advice

```
void _searchNearby(double latitude, double longitude) async {
    setState(() {
      markers.clear();
    });

    String url =
        '${googlePlaceURL}/json?location=${latitude},${longitude}&radius=1500&type=${placeType}&key=${mapAPI}';
    print(url);

    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    print('********'+'$response');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);

      print(data);

    } else {
      throw Exception('An error occurred getting places nearby');
    }

  }
```

#### Error:

```
I/flutter (10208):  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.4219983,-122.084&radius=1500&type=subway_station&key=AIzaSyAjclu-U5mgWji4rENX0LxvrfYXljfK5pg
E/flutter (10208): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Scheme not starting with alphabetic character (at character 1)
E/flutter (10208):  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=37.4...
E/flutter (10208): ^
E/flutter (10208):
E/flutter (10208): #0      _Uri._fail (dart:core/uri.dart:1623:5)
E/flutter (10208): #1      _Uri._makeScheme (dart:core/uri.dart:2184:7)
E/flutter (10208): #2      new _Uri.notSimple (dart:core/uri.dart:1465:18)
E/flutter (10208): #3      Uri.parse (dart:core/uri.dart:1022:17)
E/flutter (10208): #4      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:152:34)
E/flutter (10208): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10208): #5      BaseClient.get (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
E/flutter (10208): #6      get.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:46:36)
E/flutter (10208): #7      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20)
E/flutter (10208): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10208): #8      get (package:http/http.dart:46:5)
E/flutter (10208): #9      MapSampleState._searchNearby (package:flutter_course/Map/map.dart:44:36)
E/flutter (10208): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10208): #10     MapSampleState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_course/Map/map.dart:119:11)
```

Comment: "If there is same topic please notice me" & "I'm looking forward for your advice" is equivalent to [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variable `googlePlaceURL` start with space. Check it out, I think you can solve it in an easy way.